# Inject class into Custom Repository

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I created a class named: `S3Service` which is responsible for uploading and deleting objects from S3 (pretty much images), since I wish to use the "service" (is there a better name?) in other modules, I decided to create a custom module: `UtilsModule` where I hope to create a set of reusable shared classes. I managed to export this class from my `UtilsModule`.

```js
@Injectable()
export class S3Service {
  constructor(@InjectS3() private readonly client: S3) {}
  async removeObject(): Promise<S3.DeleteObjectOutput> {}
  async uploadObject(): Promise<S3.ManagedUpload.SendData> {}
}
```

```js
@Module({
  providers: [S3Service],
  exports: [S3Service],
})
export class UtilsModule {}
```

I did import this `UtilsModule` into the app module.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    // Other modules here
    UtilsModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And then import it into a module which needs to upload or remove objects from S3.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    // Other modules
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ProfileRepository]),
    UtilsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [ProfileController],
  providers: [ProfileService],
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

And finally inject it using the decorator `@Inject` into the desired repository.

```js
@EntityRepository(Profile)
export class ProfileRepository extends Repository<Profile> {
  constructor(
    @Inject() private s3Service: S3Service,
  ) {
    super();
  }
}
```

Here my application does compile but when I invoke this service via a Post request, a `Internal Server Error` is thrown, I started debugging with breakpoints in this "service" but it looks like the `uploadObject` function is `undefined.`

I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60347894/how-do-you-inject-a-service-in-nestjs-into-a-typeorm-repository) and apparently TypeORM repositories are not subject for DI, is there a workaround this? Should I then instantiate this class in the repository?

Comment: I am a little bit worried seeing you inject services in your repository. Is it a good practice to do so. NOT SURE. You can import repositories inside your repository. Try doing so Maybe it can help.

Comment: Not familiar with this `constructor(@InjectS3() private readonly client: S3) {}` Do  you import it like this while dealing with S3?

Comment: It's a [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ntegral/nestjs-s3), I was using it in the repository, but I decided to move it out. If this is a bad practice I may just inject it into my service and upload objects from there, I just thought having it available in the repository would be a "cleaner" solution codewise

Comment: Yes you should not inject services into your repository, as far as it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discarding injecting a service into my repository since this would be considered a bad practice, and it looks like nest doesn't allow injecting into a TypeORM repository class.

For a solution I needed to set this `S3Service` (remember to use the `Injectable()` decorator) as a provider of my `UtilsModule` and export it.

```js
@Module({
  providers: [S3Service],
  exports: [S3Service],
})
export class UtilsModule {}
```

Import it into the `AppModule` and into the module where it's needed.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    // Other modules
    UtilsModule,
  ],
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

Then I injected a repository into my service and access the db entity directly, this actually cleaned up my code quite a bit. Finally use it as a dependency in the constructor.

```js
export class ProfileService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Profile)
    private profileRepository: Repository<Profile>,
    private s3Service: S3Service,
  ) {}
}
```